# QGIS - symbol transparency not working when using string-defined fill colour

Tags: qgis, symbology, transparency-opacity, data-defined-override

I want to fill and outline polygons by using a field that contains HEX codes as a string, e.g. #99d594, as well as set the fill opacity to 25%.

I'm able to set the colours with the right field through the **Data defined override** option (Data defined override button > Field type: string > select field):

[image: data defined override]

Having the fill and outline colours set, I want to set a 25% opacity to the fill. But it displays at 100% opacity even when the opacity is set at 25%.

Below the opacity setting doesn't reflect on the map when I set the fill colour with a string field:

[image: before and after colour defined by string field]

How do I ensure that the opacity reflects when I define a fill colour with a string field?

---

**RESULT AFTER I TESTED THE ANSWER FROM J. Monticolo:**

[image: result]

Comment: Have you considered handing `rgba` values, which include transparency?

Comment: @Erik, our client works with HEX codes, but I will look into the possibility of rgba values - thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to add transparency to the HEX-code and have the value static or in a field, you can use this expression :

```sql
with_variable('fill_color', '#99d594',  -- replace with color field
with_variable('transparency', 25,  -- percent
color_rgba(
    color_part(@fill_color, 'red'),
    color_part(@fill_color, 'green'),
    color_part(@fill_color, 'blue'),
    @transparency / 100 * 255
)))
```

Comment: this works perfectly, thank you!! Going to try to add an image of my result somewhere below here...

Answer (score 2):

Ah, the more you research:

You can add transparency to HEX-codes by adding two leading characters as per this list: https://gist.github.com/lopspower/03fb1cc0ac9f32ef38f4

E.g., a leading `80` will give you a transparency of 50%, so `'#80000099'` results in a transparent dark blue.

[image]

So the code for your example would be `'#BF99d594'`.

Comment: I also came across a post that mentioned adding two leading characters, but was hoping not to fiddle too much with the client's data. But the link that you've shared is very useful though, thanks!!